# Chrome does not resize web page from Lenovo M9 tablet is zoomed

Tags: laravel, google-chrome, tablet

I created an app in Laravel, from a Lenovo M9 tablet with Firefox everything is ok even from smartphones and desktops and also other browsers everything is ok, but from Chrome for tablets the web pages are all zoomed in, I've tried everything that can be the problem ? Thank you very much in advance to the whole community..

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not provide info of what you did try, lets go trough basics. I am going to assume that the problem is Chrome since you said the other browsers did ok.

- Did you reset the zoom on Chrome to 100%?
- Did you switch the zoom on Chrome lower values to see if it has effec?
- Get into `chrome://flags/accessibility-page-zoom` and play with the controls there. Accesibility controls have reported problems with them.
- Try resseting configuration of the browser. Go into apps, select Chrome and delete the data attached to it.

I hope this helps

Comment: hi thanks for the reply, yes the problem is only the chrome tablet.. I've tried everything, played with all the controls but nothing, what else can I try?

Comment: That nothing means there was no change at all when you tried what I posted, or there were changes, but not the desired ones? About what to try, maybe Chrome is having issue with gestures or smart zoom in your tablet. Try disabling those in your tablet preferences.